# create vector from for loop and append it as new column to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, rows, calculated-columns

I want to transform my data using method described in the picture below

[image]

for that i want to create function that do this transformation, i created two for loops to pick all the values (first for loop go through columns and second for loop go through rows) and i created variables for each element of the method then i calculate my value (result of the transformation) but i don't know how to save each result in a vector so i can add the vector that contain 80 value = number of rows) to a new column in my new data

My program

```
dataa <- org_data[,1,drop=F]
# a value 
a <- 2000

#Name of the function
transformation<- function(data) {
  #The first for loop that go on columns:2 because the first column is the qualitative var
  for (i in 2:ncol(data)) {
    #take the name of a column
    colname_var <- colnames(data)[i]
    #Create vector (i have 80 rows in my data)
    my_vector <- vector("numeric", 80)
    #take the column name
    namecol= colnames(data)[i]
    for (j in 1:nrow(data)) {
     #Calculate the first value (power_two)
     power_two = data[j,i]^2
     #Calculate the second value
     a_carre = a^2
     calculation using these two values
     result_pt_mtc = (power_two + a_carre )/2
     data_ij_2 = data[j,i] / 2
     #Calculate my vector [j]
     my_vector[j]= data_ij_2 + result_pt_mtc
     #add my_vector to my new created data
     dataa <- cbind(dataa, my_vector)
      
    }
    colnames(dataa)[i] <- colname_var
    
  }
  return(dataa)
}
```

When i excute my function i got just my_vector printed several times in the console with dimension of dataa equal to 80 rows and one column

Can you tell me please where i have made mistake

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the `glog2()` transformation is to be applied on all columns of `org_data` and the transformed data is to be stored in a new dataframe `dataa`.

This is what I would in in base R:

```
# create sample dataset with 2 columns and 10 rows
nr <- 10
org_data <- data.frame(a = 1:nr, b = 10 * (1:nr))

# define function
glog2 <- function(x, a) log((x + sqrt(x*x + a*a))/2, 2)

# apply transformation
dataa <- as.data.frame(lapply(org_data, glog2, a = 2000))
```

Input data:

```
org_data
```

> ```
>     a   b
> 1   1  10
> 2   2  20
> 3   3  30
> 4   4  40
> 5   5  50
> 6   6  60
> 7   7  70
> 8   8  80
> 9   9  90
> 10 10 100
> ```

Transformed data

```
 dataa
```

> ```
>           a         b
> 1  9.966506  9.972998
> 2  9.967227  9.980211
> 3  9.967948  9.987424
> 4  9.968670  9.994636
> 5  9.969391 10.001848
> 6  9.970112 10.009059
> 7  9.970834 10.016268
> 8  9.971555 10.023477
> 9  9.972276 10.030684
> 10 9.972998 10.037889
> ```

#### Explanation

As R is working on vectors by default, there is no need to loop over single elements, normally (well, I know there are exceptions from the rule). So, the glog2() function can be applied on all elements of a vector or data.frame column at once, e.g.,

```
glog2(1:4, a = 2000)
```

> [1] 9.966506 9.967227 9.967948 9.968670

`lapply(org_data, glog2, a = 2000)` loops over the columns of `org_data` applying the glog2() function on each column (with parameter `a = 2000` passed to `glog2()`).

`lapply()` returns a list object which is turned into a data.frame, finally.